# TypeScript: How to replace a particular number in a string, and then update its value?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am very new to TypeScript, and I can't wrap my head around how to replace a particular number in a string, and then update its value.

I have a column that is full of 10-digits string (e.g. `3345678901`)

I would like to be able to:

1. Input an index number X
2. Locate the corresponding number in the string
3. Add or subtract a particular number A to/from that number to update the string
4. Update the string

A complete example below:

- Input index number "4"
- The corresponding number is `6`
- Increase that number by +2 to `8`
- Update the string to `3345878901`

I know that since string is immutable, I need to create a new string and replace necessary characters. Also in order to be able to add/subtract certain values from a value, I need to convert it to an integer first .. a bit lost here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Strings are immutable; they cannot be updated, only replaced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this.
Below code takes care of carry.

```js
const givenStr = "3345678901";

let givenStrArray = givenStr.split('').map(Number);

const inputIndex = 4;
const increaseAmount = 2;

let givenStrNumber = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < givenStrArray.length; i++) {
  givenStrNumber += givenStrArray[i] * Math.pow(10, givenStrArray.length - i - 1)
}

givenStrNumber += increaseAmount * Math.pow(10, givenStrArray.length - inputIndex - 1)

console.log(givenStrNumber);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I noticed that you edited your answer and I am wondering what is the meaning behind the newly added 'math.pow' (the two versions both worked on my end). Thank you!

Comment: The code before changed the string to an array of numbers, naively looked at the index and added `increaseAmount`. That code is difficult to account for carry. For example, if you added `increaseAmount = 3` to the given digit `8`, you would get `11`. Then you have to check if it's greater than 10, look for `inputIndex - 1` and add a number there, etc. etc. The edited code fully converts the string to a single number so the addition is done automatically.

Answer (score 0):

```
const inputStr = "3345678901";
const inputIndex = 4;
const increaseAmount = 2;

let x = Number(inputStr[inputIndex]) + increaseAmount

const result = inputStr.substring(0,inputIndex) + x + inputStr.substring(inputIndex + 1)

console.log(result);
```