# TypeScript: How to replace a particular number in a string (a combination of numerical and non-numerical values), and then update its value?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I asked a similar question here [TypeScript: How to replace a particular number in a string, and then update its value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71949890/typescript-how-to-replace-a-particular-number-in-a-string-and-then-update-its)

Really appreciate the answers there. It answered my questions.

I am run into a new issue. Thought it s more helpful to raise a new question while referring to the old question.

I have a column that is full of 10-digits string.

Sometimes that entire 10-digits only contain numerical values (e.g. `3345678901`), but sometimes there is dash included (e.g. `3345678---`)

I would like to be able to:

1. Input an index number X
2. Locate the corresponding number in the string
3. Add or subtract a particular number A to/from that number to update the string
4. Update the string

Example 1 (all numerical): `3345678901`

- Input index number "4"
- The corresponding number is `6`
- Increase that number by +2 to `8`
- Update the string to `3345878901`

Example 2 (numerical & non-numerical):  `3345678---`

- Input index number "4"
- The corresponding number is `6`
- Increase that number by +2 to `8`
- Update the string to `3345878---`

Example 3 (numerical & non-numerical): `3345678---`

- Input index number "7"
- The corresponding value is `-`
- Increase (or rather, update) that number by +2 to `2`
- Update the string to `33458782--`

For example 1, I know I could do following (as a contributor from the OG post has pointed out):

```
const givenStr = "3345678901";

let givenStrArray = givenStr.split('').map(Number);

const inputIndex = 4;
const increaseAmount = 2;

givenStrNumber += increaseAmount

console.log(givenStrNumber);
```

But, how do I go about Example 2 and 3 though? Since there are string '-' involved? In this case `map(Number)` would lead to Null values that would break the code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: From what I see, you don't have to convert the whole string into number, just the digit (or dash) at that specific index

Comment: Also, what's the desired behavior if the original digit is `8` or `9`? Does it become `0`/`1`, or `10`/`11`?

Comment: "Update the string to..." Javascript strings are immutable, you can't update them.

Answer (score 0):

Check for `NaN`. This is a tiny snippet that would give you a hint:

```js
// ...
// ...
const increment = 2;

let givenStrArray = 
  givenStr
   .split('')
   .map((digiit) => isNaN(digit) ? increment : Number(digit + increment);

// ...
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
let str = '3345678---'

let NumericStrArray = str.split('').map(x => Number.isNaN(Number(x)) ? x: Number(x))

let ipIndex = 7
let incAmount = 2
let val = NumericStrArray[ipIndex]
NumericStrArray[ipIndex] = typeof val === 'string' ? incAmount : val + incAmount

let result = NumericStrArray.join('')
```

Comment: `isNaN` is not bad practise as you suggest. Understanding the differences between `Number.isNaN` and `isNaN` is what makes their use valid. `Number.isNaN("-") = false`, `isNaN("-") = true`. `isNan` first attempts to convert to number and then checks for `NaN`. You are essentially doing exactly the same with `Number(x)`. This is an opinion based assertion you are using to attack perfectly valid answers.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, I got confused based on my usage of `isNaN` and `Number.isNaN`. And just with half baked info shouldn't have criticize other's approach as wrong. Sincere Apologies.

Comment: Not a problem Bishwajit jha. It's fine to say something is "best practice" with certain things for sure. Just make sure if you do, link to some documentation on the matter so others can learn from it, or just link to documentation explaining usage. Your actual link to the `isNaN` docs was perfectly valid! You should have left it in! :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple little snippet. Break the sting apart, map through each item, when we find the index we need to update we update it and return it, then join them all back together.

Multiple conditional ternary operator have been used here, you can find out more about how they work here: [Conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

```js
const givenStr = "334567----", 
  inputIndex = 6,
  increaseAmount = 2

let givenNumber = givenStr
  .split('')
  .map((v,i) => i === inputIndex ? isNaN(v) ? increaseAmount : +v + increaseAmount : v)
  .join('')

console.log(givenNumber);
```